# Ansible conditional element in html body

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible task that uses a http POST method to create objects via an API.
The two commented lines for the min and max value should be only contained in the HTML body is they are set in the input variable.
If the value is not set the whole variable cannot be in the body. I have tried to omit(NULL) or set to 0, but then the API complains that this variable should be only provided for objects of item.type int.

I guess the proper way would be to create a Jinja template and condition that checks the item.type. But I wonder if there is a way in Ansible in general to conditionally include a variable or not.

```yaml
- name: Create Custom fields within NetBox
  uri:
    url: "{{ netbox_url }}/api/extras/custom-fields/"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Authorization: "Token {{ netbox_token }}"
      Accept: "application/json"
    return_content: yes
    body_format: json
    body:
      label: "{{ item.label }}"
      type: "{{ item.type }}"
      content_types: "{{ item.content_types | default(omit) }}"
      required: "{{ item.required | default(False) }}"
      description: "{{ item.description | default(omit) }}"
      weight: "{{ item.weight | default(100) }}"
      filter_logic: "{{ item.filter_logic | default(loose) }}"
      default: "{{ item.default | default(omit) }}"
      choices: "{{ item.choices | default(omit) }}"
      #validation_minimum: "{{ item.validation_minimum | default(0) }}"
      #validation_maximum: "{{ item.validation_maximum | default(0) }}"
      validation_regex: "{{ item.validation_regex | default(omit) }}"
    status_code: [200, 201]
  loop: "{{ custom_fields }}"
  run_once: yes
  when:
    - item.name not in names
    - netbox_state != 'absent'
  register: netbox_custom_fields
  tags: custom_fields
```

Comment: did you try `{{ item.validation_minimum | default(omit) }}`. I'm not sure, if I understand your comment with  omit(NULL)....

Comment: @Zeitounator - I've tested that with my Ansible 2.9 and a simple HTTP server that just returns the request body. And default(omit) works on the body parameter too.I think also - this is normal, because Ansible and the uri module both use the YAML+Jinja parser. And as long the uri module isn't making its only parser (why ever) the syntax works for sub, subsub, subsubsub parameters too.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your example is that each element in `custom_fields` contains a set of keys that should all end-up in `body`. In other words there are no keys in each of the elements that should not be included in the body. (If this is not the case please edit your question with a sample data).

There are also some keys that might not be in an element but that must be included in the body with a default value.

So the final problem comes down to defining a dictionary of default mandatory keys with their values and combine it to each element. I tried to build up an example from your question but you may have to adapt a bit. Specifically, I dropped the condition you had in your uri task for simplicity. Meanwhile, this should be enough to understand.

```yaml
---
- name: apply defaults to a dictionary
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    # This is our list of dicts to loop over.
    # Totaly made up for the example.
    custom_fields:
      - label: title
        type: string
        description: personal title
        choices: ["Mr", "Mme", "Ms", "Pr", "Dr"]
      - label: fname
        type: string
        description: first name
        required: true
      - label: lname
        type: string
        description: last name
        required: true
      - label: mname
        type: string
        description: middle name
        weight: 10
        filter_logic: ignore
      - label: whatever
        type: float
        content_types: toto
        filter_logic: tight
        default: 0
        validation_minimum: 0
        validation_maximum: 10000000
        validation_regex: ^\\d+$

    # These are the defaults to apply to each item above
    custom_field_defaults:
      required: false
      weight: 100
      filter_logic: loose

  tasks:
    - name: show what our body would look like in a uri call
      vars:
        body: "{{ custom_field_defaults | combine(item) }}"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ body }}"
      loop: "{{ custom_fields }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.label }}"
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [apply defaults to a dictionary] ***************************************

TASK [show what our body would look like in a uri call] *********************
ok: [localhost] => (item=title) => {
    "msg": {
        "choices": [
            "Mr",
            "Mme",
            "Ms",
            "Pr",
            "Dr"
        ],
        "description": "personal title",
        "filter_logic": "loose",
        "label": "title",
        "required": false,
        "type": "string",
        "weight": 100
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=fname) => {
    "msg": {
        "description": "first name",
        "filter_logic": "loose",
        "label": "fname",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "weight": 100
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=lname) => {
    "msg": {
        "description": "last name",
        "filter_logic": "loose",
        "label": "lname",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "weight": 100
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=mname) => {
    "msg": {
        "description": "middle name",
        "filter_logic": "ignore",
        "label": "mname",
        "required": false,
        "type": "string",
        "weight": 10
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=whatever) => {
    "msg": {
        "content_types": "toto",
        "default": 0,
        "filter_logic": "tight",
        "label": "whatever",
        "required": false,
        "type": "float",
        "validation_maximum": 10000000,
        "validation_minimum": 0,
        "validation_regex": "^\\\\d+$",
        "weight": 100
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `default(omit)` to avoid sending undefined values. Here an example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - uri:
        url: "http://localhost/api/test"
        method: "POST"
        headers:
          Accept: "application/json"
        return_content: true
        body_format: json
        body:
          var1: "{{ var1 | default('1') }}"
          var2: "{{ var2 | default(omit) }}"
      register: content

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ content }}"
```

On the given uri in the example is just a simple responder that echos the request body. The output will be:

```
TASK [uri] ***********************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
    changed: false
    connection: close
    content: '{"body":"{\"var1\": \"1\"}"}'
    content_length: '28'
    content_type: application/json
    cookies: {}
    cookies_string: ''
    date: Mon, 10 Jan 2022 08:38:33 GMT
    elapsed: 0
    failed: false
    json:
      body: '{"var1": "1"}'
    msg: OK (28 bytes)
    redirected: false
    server: nginx/1.21.5
    status: 200
    url: http://localhost/api/test
```

So, the `uri` module will get only the body attribute `var1`. `var2` is omitted.

Comment: Removed my above comment after this brilliant demonstration of `omit` working inside the `body` parameter. ;)

Comment: Yes, I did it ;-)